# Load Random APi Content

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How do I change this function to load content randomly from the API? I want to pass in a random integer and change the end point of the url.

```
NSString* WebServiceURL =@"http://movie-quotes.herokuapp.com/api/v1/quotes";
```

to this

`http://movie-quotes.herokuapp.com/api/v1/quotes/2`

where the number at the end is the quote number

Here is my relevant code:

```
-(void)LoadQuotesRandom
 {


randomQuotes = nil;

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    // Load the JSON string from our web serivce (in a background thread)
    NSDictionary * dictionary = [JSONHelper loadJSONDataFromURL:WebServiceURL];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        randomQuotes = [NSMutableArray array];

        // Iterate through the array of Customer records in the dictionary
        for (NSDictionary * oneQuote in dictionary)
        {
            Quotes* newQuotes =[[Quotes alloc] init];
            // Add our new Customer record to our NSMutableArray
            newQuotes.Quote = [oneQuote objectForKey:@"content"];
            newQuotes.FilmName =[oneQuote objectForKey:@"film"];
            [randomQuotes addObject:newQuotes];

        }

    });
});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To restate more simply, I think you want a url string with a random integer suffix.

```
NSInteger randomInt = arc4random_uniform(SOME_MAX);
NSString *baseUrl = @"http://movie-quotes.herokuapp.com/api/v1/quotes";
NSString *webServiceUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%ld", baseUrl, randomInt];
```

You'll need to #define SOME_MAX for the largest quote index one can request.

I suggest you separate this completely for the code that makes the request.  Get one piece working that does any request given a string describing the url, and a separate piece that generates these url strings.